# Google cloud Linux instance is unable to login suddenly

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

This is a free 3cx google linux instance we have been using for past 3 weeks. All of sudden i am unable to login VM using Putty/SSH or Google cloud console and getting ran out of storage errors. I have resized the disk but still keeps getting errors. Below is few lines from serial log -

```
localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: Activating Google Compute Engine OS Login.

Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/ssh/sed5ok0QR: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/ssh/sedsnBxDR: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/ssh/sedC8TiHR: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/sedwyzwwR: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/sedfzoX9P: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/pam.d/sedk4JABH: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/pam.d/sed0i1OtH: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/pam.d/sedyhvdhH: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/pam.d/sedTaGMlH: No space left on device
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google_accounts_daemon[760]: Restarting sshd.
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Aug 21 09:47:55 localhost google-accounts: ERROR Exception calling the response handler. [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'].#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 196, in WatchMetadata#012    handler(response)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_daemon.py", line 263, in HandleAccounts#012    self.utils.SetConfiguredUsers(desired_users.keys())#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py", line 276, in SetConfiguredUsers#012    mode='w', prefix=prefix, delete=True) as updated_users:#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 463, in NamedTemporaryFile#012    dir = gettempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 275, in gettempdir#012    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 217, in _get_default_tempdir#012    ("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))#012IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
```

Equivalent command line

Did anyone encounter this error if so can help resolve this?

Comment: `No space left on device`: delete some files to make space.

Comment: i cannot connect to instance - ssh

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google cloud, but usually there is a way to use the local console of the instance. About the resize, usually the position is not resized as well when you resize the disk, but again, I'm not familiar with GCE. I'd just deploy a larger instance.

Comment: If you run ssh from the command line (using `-i` to specify the key) and use a key that you have previously used to log in on that VM, you should be able to log in even if the disk is full.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your boot disk is full, preventing you to access the instance via SSH. You can increase the boot disk size from the cloud console in compute Engine/instances menu.
More details are available on GCP public documentation at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk).

There enter in the instance settings, select the boot disk, edit and raise the size.
Don't increase the size too much as you won't be able to decrease it afterwards.

Then restart the instance so the Operating System takes in account the partition resize.
You should then be able to log in via SSH.

You'll be able then do some cleaning after finding the reason why the filesystem is getting full.

Comment: Thanks Django. I tried that, now i seem to be getting different errors related to NIC. I didnt change instance NIC settings wonder what triggered it-                                                                            
Aug 21 11:28:37 localhost dhclient[579]: DHCPACK of 10.142.0.2 from 169.254.169.254

Aug 21 11:28:37 localhost ifup[522]: DHCPACK of 10.142.0.2 from 169.254.169.254

Aug 21 11:28:37 localhost ifup[522]: hostname: name too long

Comment: If the server is not reachable because its hostname is too long, you could try to use a startup script on the instance to modify its hostname. Here is the link explaining how to uses startup scripts. [link]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: Hi, I'm glad you could resolve it, please consider accepting my answer if it helped in the resolution.